# Is there a simple way to stream a non-public IP camera into a website?

Tags: javascript, php, ip-camera

I'm trying to embed a non-public rtsp camera into a website without third-party software or plugins and capable for all browsers and devices.

I found a workaround that works but it is not elegant. It consists in taking continuous snapshots of the camera from a jpeg camera access url  and copy that to a file with a running php script on the server:

```
 <?php
 while (True) {
    copy('http://192.168.x.x/snap.jpg?JpegSize=M&JpegCam=1', './webcam/frame.jpg'); // local URL from my camera to obtain jpg snapshot
    usleep (150000); // microseconds!!
 }
 ?>
```

Then, on the client browser, this served page contains a javascript function that is responsible with refreshing this snapshot and produce a webcam effect:

```
<script>
function reloadWebcam() {
   var now = new Date();
   document.images['webcam'].src = './webcam/frame.jpg?' + now.getTime();
}
</script>

...

<img name="webcam" align="center" width="640" height="480" scrolling="no">
<script>
setInterval('reloadWebcam()', 300); // 300 miliseconds
</script>
```

So, it works but I'm looking for:

a) an easy solution but more elegant than this.

b) an improvement to this solution with a way to avoid subprocess of copy on server and/or avoid javascript refresh in client browser.

Comment: a. 'More elegant' is subjective, what exactly do you mean?. b. If you have a private camera you'll have to move the files to a publicly accessible location somehow; and if you want the files to be refreshed automatically you'll need some form of automatic refresh. I'm not sure what answer you expect, sounds like you have a perfectly functional solution!

Comment: The way you are doing it is really the only way you can do it as most other ways have now been blocked by most browsers, but the last time tried this, the QuickTime player plugin still worked on many browsers, but even doing it that way outputted some very bad / slow video. The reason why that seems to happen is that the QuickTime player uses delay buffering ...

Comment: @JeffUK only I'm trying to find a better solution a) As simple as I can write `<video controls preload="auto" src="video/sample.mp4"></video>`  for MP4 video, I would to do the same with rstp ;) b) Certainly it is functional but I think it is not efficient to have a php process running in the server for refresh every camera that I want to show. Maybe it is even worse than javascript to refresh it in client side. Obviously in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @StephanieTemple. Really when I have started to deal with this, I have discover complex solutions or even payment services.